# Radio Button Values are not showing the values

Tags: radio-button

I dont get the values in the table. Please help me.

```
var myName = document.getElementById("name");
var age = document.getElementById("dob");
var job = document.getElementById("job")
var marriage = document.getElementById("marriage")
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/shejus/prf4h523/7/)

Comment: That's because you are trying to get element by Id and you have marriage as name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mcount=document.getElementsByName("marriage").length;
    for(i=0;i<mcount;i++)
    {
    alert(document.getElementsByName("marriage")[i].value);
    }
```

You can try this to get value of radio by using name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this in your case:

```
var marriage = document.getElementsByName( 'marriage');
```

But you will get an array and therefore your have to index all of them (I only get the "male" checkbox here):

```
document.getElementsByName( 'marriage')[1];
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prf4h523/8/)